# makeMarker() Google Maps Sidebar Format

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, sidebar

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Firstly, I am relatively new to this, so may I ask for your patience please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/test.php) page which allows users to show and hide Google Map markers and associated 'Sidebar' items pertinent to the 'Category' check box they select.

What I'm now trying to, and having great difficulty in doing, is to change the format of the sidebar, so that it resembles the one shown on [this](http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/boundsbox/makemarker_sidebar_plain.htm) page.

As with the example from the link above, I'd also like to add the functionality whereby if the map marker is clicked, the associated sidebar item is highlighted.

I've been trying to get this to work for quite some time now, but I just seem to be going around in circles.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may be able to go about achieving this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the sidebar? I seem to be missing it..

Comment: Hi @Mansfield, thank you for taking the time to look at and, reply to my post. My apologies, I should have perhaps made a little clearer. If you use the first link I provide in my original post, it will open a page which shows 4 check boxes, a map and two list items in orange. There are two items shown in my example and it is these items that are the 'Sidebar'. The check boxes then determine which category of markers are shown on the map. Selecting and de-selecting these will make the sidebar items appear and disappear from the 'Sidebar'. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Okay, I understand. If it's still unanswered by this evening when I get home I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: HI @Mansfield, thank you very much for this. I look forward to hearing from you. All the best and kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a go, just replace your following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
   infowindow.setContent(contentString);
   infowindow.open(map,marker); 
});
```

for this one:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
   infowindow.setContent(contentString);
   $("#sidebar a").css('background-color','');//remove sidebar links back colors
   sidebarlink = $("#sidebar a:contains('"+marker.mydescription+"')");
   sidebarlink.css('background-color','#58FAD0');
   infowindow.open(map,marker); 
});
```

that will set a background color to the sidebar link, you can change the color to whatever you want or add any other css styles you prefer to your link.

Also make sure your description text in the `mydescription` variable does never contains a quot `'` or double quote `"` as would make above code to fail.

Let me know if this work as you expected.

Also, if you wish to also remove the background color from the sidebar links when you click anywhere your map(e.g. clicking outside of markers) do it by replacing your following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() { 
   infowindow.close(); 
});
```

for this one:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() { 
   $("#sidebar a").css('background-color','');//remove sidebar links back colors
   infowindow.close(); 
});
```

To get the background color changing on hover on sidebar links (issue 1), just add the following piece of css code to any of your `<style type="text/css">` blocks:

```
#sidebar a:hover{
   background-color: #58FAD0;   
}​
```

Comment: Hi @Nelson, thanks for taking the time to put this together.Sadly, it doesn't entirely work.There appears to be no change to the background colour on 'hover over' of the sidebar list.Also if the user selects a marker, the background to the linked 'sidebar' item does change colour. However, it doesn't revert back to the default background colour when the second marker is selected. I've updated the link I included in my original post to illustrate this. I'm also a little uneasy about the 'mydescription' not being able to contain `code` or ". This restricts the entries made by users. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM thanks for a good feedback, you spotted two issues, 1) being hover not working and 2) being the background colors not be clean-out. I've fixed issue number 2), see my update answer, where I also put some code in case you also want to clean the background when clicking outside markers but in the map, that behaviour is not done by your showed page http://koti.mbnet.fi/.... but in my opinion that could be an improvement in your page.

Comment: I'v just updated my answer to fix issue 1) see my css for the hover effect.

Comment: Hi @Nelson, this is really very very good. It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for all your time, trouble and effort. I'm awarding the bounty to you. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM thanks for the kind words, I'm very glad you like it :-)